# Bind Labels to selected item in WPF C#

Tags: c#, binding, listbox, label

It's possible that my question has already been answered but I want to see if I can fix the problem in my own context.

The problem is that I have a ListBox containing cars, if you check the code you see that there is a GridView with Labels in it, these labels get the first item (first car) but I want it to get the car that you select in the ListBox.

As I said, there may already be an answer that I haven't found yet but any help would be appreciated!

```
<Window x:Class="WBS.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WBS"
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="mainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="353.2" Width="696.2">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FFDFE4E3">
        <Button x:Name="btInfo" Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btInfo_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btEditCar" Content="Bewerk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btEditCar_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbCars" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="140" Margin="184,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>
        <Button x:Name="btAddCar" Content="Voeg toe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btAddCar_Click"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="lbFleets" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="140" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144" SelectionChanged="lbFleets_SelectionChanged"/>

        <Grid Margin="515,50,9.6,53.6" Name="grdCarOverview" Background="#FF91908F">
            <Label x:Name="lbBrand" Content="{Binding Path=[0].Brand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="146" BorderBrush="#FFB3B3B3" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbColor" Content="{Binding Path=[0].Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Width="146" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFB3B3B3"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbConstructionYear" Content="{Binding Path=[0].ConstructionYear}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="85" Width="146" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="#FFB3B3B3" BorderThickness="1"/>
            <Label Content="De eerste auto:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Label Content="Lijst met vloten:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
        <Label Content="Lijst auto's per vloot:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="184,19,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="btAddFleet" Content="Voeg toe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,206,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btAddFleet_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btEditFleet" Content="Bewerk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btEditFleet_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btRemoveCar" Content="Verwijder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="336,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btRemoveCar_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btRemoveFleet" Content="Verwijder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,277,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btRemoveFleet_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }
public Car SelectedCar { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Fleet> Fleets { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add binding to your `ListBox` control

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbCars" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Cars }"
             SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCarId}" 
             SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
             Height="140" Margin="184,50,0,0"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>
```

in CS file ,making dummy data

```
 public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>
 {
     new Car{Id = 0, Name = "Audi"},
     new Car{Id = 1, Name = "Honda"},
     new Car{Id = 2, Name = "Toyota"},
 };

 public int SelectedCarId { get; set; }
```

`SelectedCarId` will hold the Id of Car selected.
 Same goes for `lbFleets` ListBox as well.